# Горизонтальное меню, выходящее за пределы основного макета

Tags: меню, html, css

Как с помощью `css` сделать горизонтальное меню, выходящее за пределы основного макета?

Реализовано на сайте [TeamWebUSA](http://www.dallasprowebdesigners.com/).

Горизонтальное меню стоит как будто поверх тела сайта. Как я понял, сделать это можно с помощью `z-index`. Но когда ставлю на тэг `wrapper  z-index 1`, а на тэг `ul` (меню) `z-index 9999`, ничего не происходит.

```
# menu{
    background: url(../images/menu-1.png) repeat-x scroll 0% 0% transparent; 
    position: relative; 
    padding-bottom:70px;
    }

. menu-1 {
    width:2000px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    }

# Menu - id блока поверх ul, .menu-1  класс ul
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что по мимо `z-index: 9999` для ul нужно поставить ещё `position:absolute` или `position:relative`. (на момент написания сообщения этих стилей у него не было)

Comment: Вправо тянется без проблем, а влево нет. Можно подвинуть с помощью left:-x но нужно чтобы это меню было резиновым.

Comment: Зачем что-то двигать?

Comment: По умолчанию меню по центру. После добавления 
. menu-1 {
    width:2000px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    }
правый край растягиваться до конца экрана, а левый край стоит на месте по центру.

Comment: А без position всё нормально было? Просто без position z-index не работает. Но может быть меню на самом деле у вас не по центру? А например в начале идёт td или div размером как половина экрана, а далее меню прилепленное к левому краю? Поставте border у каждого элемента и сразу всё будет понятно.

Comment: Для того чтобы выстрогать css нужно видеть html! z-index тут вообще не в тему!

Comment: Что, помогло растановка border? Или своё решение какое-то?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос реально тяжко написан))) Понял в чем дело) Тут с z-index не нужно парится...

допустим:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div#container { width: 100%; }
    div#subcontainer { width: 960px; margin: 0px auto; }
    div.menu { background: #e5e5e5; height: 40px; }
    div.header { background: #3d3d3d; height: 100px; }
    div.content { padding: 5px; }
    div.footer { background: #e5e5e5; height: 50px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="menu">
       <div id="subcontainer">Menu</div>
      </div>
      <div class="header">
       <div id="subcontainer">Header</div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
       <div id="subcontainer">Content</div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
       <div id="subcontainer">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

//#subcontainer основная ширина шаблона, div'ы на уровень выше заливаем background изображением. на примере цветом.

Comment: У меня все по центру по умолчанию. Все вставил в тело html, не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то ничего не надо мудрить с z-index-ами и position:

```
<div class="menu_wrap">
     <div class="menu">
           Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS для наглядности:

```
.menu_wrap{
     height: 30px;
     background-color: #000;
}
.menu{
     width: 960px;
     color: #fff;
}
```

А если не правильно, то пишите вопрос яснее ;)